# Dataset of regular expressions for named entity recognition

Tags: data-request, nlp

I am looking for a dataset containing:

- regular expressions useful for named entity recognition. The regular expressions can be used either as a feature or directly as a rule (in case it always correctly capture a named entity).

Example:

- `r'(\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4})'` captures date entities formatted like `03/16/1946`.

I mostly interested in texts written in English.

Comment: Something like http://www.regxlib.com/ ?

Comment: @BarryCarter yes

Comment: So there you go?